# What is the difference between semiring and hemiring?

Tags: ring-theory, semiring

An algebraic structure equipped two binary operations is called a semiring if both the binary operations are associative and one of the operations distributes over the other. Hemiring also seems to be similarly defined. I am confused, where lies the difference?

Comment: It is hard to answer your question because the terminology is not totally settled, nor is it likely ever to be.  All you can do is take two sources and compare to see what is different.  Golan's book *Semirings and their applications* distinguishes the two as Eric Towers mentions: the semiring has a multiplicative identity.

Comment: Does "seems to be defined similarly" mean that you do not have the definition for hemiring? It is impossible to compare two things when you don't have one of them.

Comment: @rschwieb .. downvoting, the reason being hard to answer

Answer (score 1):

Semirings have a multiplicative identity.

(Using a standard, but silly misspelling), hemirngs need not have a multiplicative identity.

Comment: You have no idea how long I debated removing the prefix's "i"...

Comment: Some authors prefer to ignore the requirements of both additive and multiplicative identities in a semiring. So, i am still not cleared.

Comment: @gete : This nomenclature is not 100% settled.  You have to consult your author to see which choices were made.  [Golan, 2005](http://moonstone.math.ncku.edu.tw/AlgebraConference/golantalk.pdf) for instance, requires a semiring to have a nonzero unit.  [Ali et al. 2017](http://article.sciencepublishinggroup.com/pdf/10.11648.j.pamj.20170601.16.pdf) allows unitless hemirings.  Both require additive identities.